# Asp.net WebForms Repeater OnClick not firing when inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Back story, I'm reinventing pagination to work off a datasource call that I can only really get the number of results and current page on.  I know what page i'm on, I know how many pages there are.  I want to render the repeater with the currently selected item always in the middle so I'm going to rebuild the list here on every postback.  For some reason though none of my click events are firing.  The other answers on the site fix this by stating, "Don't rebuild the list on postback.", but that's exactly what I need to do here.

My ascx code looks like the following:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="PaginationRepeater" runat="server"
            OnItemDataBound="PaginationRepeater_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID = "PaginationLink" runat="server" 
                        Text = '<%#Container.DataItem.ToString()%>'
                        CommandArgument = '<%#Container.DataItem.ToString()%>'
                        CommandName="WasClicked"
                        OnCommand="PaginationLink_Command"
                        OnClick="PaginationLink_Click">
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Properties in play:

```
public int ResultCount { get; set; }
public bool ShowPaging { get; set; }
public int PreviousPageNumber { get; set; }
public int CurrentPageNumber { get; set; }
public List<int> PageNumbers { get; set; }
public int NextPageNumber { get; set; }
```

The PaginationLink_Command and PaginationLink_Click commands just throw a not implemented exception for now.  Hopefully at some point I'll be able to hit these lines of code.

```
private void Link_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
private void Link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
protected void PaginationLink_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
protected void PaginationLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Hopefully someone out there is good with webforms and willing to help.

**Update:**  Answering how I load the data into the repeater:

```
public override void OnContentLoaded()
{
    base.OnContentLoaded();
    Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
}

protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentPage = 1; // TODO: get from pagination.
    int productCount = LoadProducts(currentPage);
    LoadPager(currentPage, productCount);
}

public void LoadPager(int currentPage, int resultCount)
{
    int itemsPerPage = 9;
    int displayedPages = 9;
    ShowPaging = resultCount > itemsPerPage;
    if (!ShowPaging)
        return;

    int maxPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)(resultCount / itemsPerPage)) + 1;
    if (currentPage > maxPages)
        currentPage = maxPages;

    int start = Enumerable.Max(new[] { currentPage - (displayedPages / 2), 1 });
    int end = Enumerable.Min(new[] { start + displayedPages, maxPages });

    CurrentPageNumber = currentPage;
    PreviousPageNumber = currentPage - 1 > 1 ? currentPage - 1 : 1;
    NextPageNumber = currentPage + 1 <= maxPages ? currentPage + 1 : maxPages;
    PageNumbers = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1).ToList();

    PaginationRepeater.DataSource = PageNumbers;
    PaginationRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

The TLDR is that I'm rebinding during the LoadComplete event.

Comment: How do you populate the Repeater with data? You have a typo in event name - `_Click1` vs `_Click`.

Comment: I only see a `PaginationLink_Click1` method, not a `PaginationLink_Click` method. Other that that it all seems ok.

Comment: Sorry, i have regenerated the click event methods a number of times and had to delete that 1.  I'll update it.